# Hiding a 'removable device'

Tags: fstab, tmpfs

I have my downloads folder mounted as a tmpfs, achieved by putting this line into fstab:

```
tmpfs /home/sam/Downloads tmpfs defaults,noatime,mode=1777 0 0
```

However, one unfortunate side effect is that this folder now appears in the Unity launcher as a removable drive, and in the side pane of nautilus as well. Is there any way I can tell Ubuntu that it's not something I want attention drawn to, and that it's just another normal folder?

Comment: Have you tried several options to add to your fstab rule?
For instance, if you use `code` noauto, your filesystem won't be mounted automatically. When you use this option, you must explicitly mount your filesystem